# info and debug logging do not show

Tags: python, logging

i am trying to use the loggings as shown below.the .debug and info do not display any thing
please let me know why the debug and info logging do not shown up

**code**:

```
import logging
class varargs:

def __new__(cls):
    print("in object creation")
    cls.callBeforeInit()
    instance = super(varargs, cls).__new__(cls)
    return instance
    #return object.__new__(cls)
    
def __init__(self):
    print("in object indtansiation")
    pass

@classmethod
def callBeforeInit(cls):
    #print("called before init")
    logging.debug('called before __init__') #<--never gets displayed

def varargsMethod(self,*args):
    print(args)

def varKwArgsMethod(self, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
```

v = varargs()
v.varargsMethod(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

Answer (score 1):

The default level for logging is `WARNING`. That means that by default only logs of that or a higher level are shown. You can change the level like this:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel("DEBUG")

logging.debug("this will show")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but would you please tell me where is the optimum place for this statement?i mean should i add it to __init__ or __new__`?

Comment: It depends. My recommendation would be to add it at the module level. So right after the `import logging`. That way the logging level will be set at the earliest possible point. @LetsamrIt